# Formula de Selección en Crystal Reports con VS 2019

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

Estoy trabajando en la actualización de un proyecto en Vb 2019 y tiene una serie de reportes en CR, cuando llamo al informe para visualizarlo en el CrViewer no me reconoce la formula de seleccion de registros, cuando en las versiones anteriores en Vb6 y en VB 2013 funcionaba perfectamente, no se han realizado cambios al informe ni a la formula original, y no arroja ningún óigo e error , les paso el código de la función:

```
Private Sub RptAsientos()
Dim Report As New CrystalReport1
Report.Refresh()
Report.VerifyDatabase()
Report.RecordSelectionFormula = "{Consulta4.IdEmpresa} = " & NroEmpresa & " and {Consulta4.IdEjercicio}= " & NroEjercicio & " and {Consulta4.IdLibro} = " & NroDesde & "and {Consulta4.AsientoNro} = " & NroHasta
CRV1.ReportSource = Report
Report.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Te sale algún error? Por favor añádelo a tu pregunta.

Comment: no genera ningún error, simplemente no reconoce la formula, al cargar el informe debería solamente imprimir los registros seleccionados, pero imprime todo el archivo

Comment: finalmente generé una consulta sql que pasa solamente los datos que necesito cada vez que debo imprimir